# How to edit a line of data in text file

Tags: .net, vb.net

I would like to edit specific line in text file using vb.net. 
Example below is my data in text file:

**Port1.txt**

> data1
>
> data2
>
> data3
>
> data4
>
> data5
>
> data6
>
> data7

I would like to edit data5 (line 5)  in the text file to dataXX. How do I do that?

So far by using the code below, I only can access all the data listed instead of a row data.

```
 Dim path As String = "c:\Users\EliteBook\Desktop\Port1.txt"

    Dim readText() As String = File.ReadAllLines(path)
    Dim s As String
    For Each s In readText
        MsgBox(s)
    Next
```

This would give me an output in msgbox of all the data listed in the text file. How do I access a specific row of data instead of all of it? I have edited this question according to Nahum Litvin suggestion via [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nahum's answer is correct, but it's in C#.  Here is the equivalent VB.NET, using the data in the code you posted in your question:

```
Dim path As String = "c:\Users\EliteBook\Desktop\Port1.txt"
Dim readText As String() = File.ReadAllLines(path)
readText(4) = "dataXX"
File.WriteAllLines(path, readText)
```

The above code reads the file into an array of string, one line per element.  It then changes element 4 (the 5th line) to "dataXX", in this line of code:

```
readText(4) = "dataXX"
```

Then it saves the array back to the file, with line 5 reading "dataXX".

Answer (score 2):

ur using the wrong methods.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx

approxemently like this I have no compiler at hand

```
string path = @"c:\temp\MyTest.txt";
string[] readText = File.ReadAllLines(path);
string[4] = "new data";
File.WriteAllLines(path, readText );
```

Comment: I have edited the question. ReadAllLines allows me to read all the data in text file. How do I specify where to stop? Plus I don't get why they used Dim s as string and a for each s.

Comment: `File.ReadAllLines` returns an array of string, one array element per line.  There is no "stop" - it reads the entire file into the array.  You access the line you want by it's corresponding index in the array - but don't forget that arrays are zero-based, so line 5 would be index 4 in the array.

Comment: @Tim, how do i access the array then, because when i used MsgBox(s(0)). It leads into displaying data of column 0. which is "d".